# Replace a given character in a string variable with a character from another string variable of equal length

Tags: r, regex

I have a data frame with two string variables with an equal number of characters.  These strings represent a student responses for some exam.  The first string contains a + sign for each question answered correctly and the incorrect response for each incorrect item.  The second string contains all the correct answers.  I want to replace all the + signs in the first string with the correct answer from the second string.  A simplified heuristic data set can be created with this code:

```
df <- data.frame(v1 = c("+AA+B", "D++CC", "A+BAD"), 
                 v2 = c("DBBAD", "BDCAD","CDCCA"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

So the + signs in `df$v1` need to be replaced w/ the letters in `df$v2` that are the same distance from the start of the string.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When `df$v1` and `df$v2` are characters we may use

```
regmatches(df$v1, gregexpr("\\+", df$v1)) <- regmatches(df$v2, gregexpr("\\+", df$v1))
```

That is,

```
df <- data.frame(v1 = c("+AA+B", "D++CC", "A+BAD"), 
                 v2 = c("DBBAD", "BDCAD", "CDCCA"), 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
rg <- gregexpr("\\+", df$v1)
regmatches(df$v1, rg) <- regmatches(df$v2, rg)
df
#      v1    v2
# 1 DAAAB DBBAD
# 2 DDCCC BDCAD
# 3 ADBAD CDCCA
```

`rg` contains the positions of "+" in `df$v1`, and we conveniently exploit `regmatches` to replace those matches in `df$v1` with whatever is in `df$v2` at the same positions.

Comment: Awesome.  This works great. I will edit my code to prevent it from creating factors.

Answer (score 3):

This one seems valid, too:

```
mapply(function(x, y) paste0(ifelse(x == "+", y, x), collapse = ""), 
                 strsplit(as.character(df$v1), ""), strsplit(as.character(df$v2), ""))
#[1] "DAAAB" "DDCCC" "ADBAD"
```

Comment: great use of `ifelse`

Answer (score 2):

Most likely there's a better approach but here's on where I make the two columns into matrices and then a lookup key:

```
## df<-data.frame(v1 = c("+AA+B", "D++CC", "A+BAD"), v2 = c("DBBAD", "BDCAD","CDCCA"))
dats <- lapply(df, function(x) do.call(rbind, strsplit(as.character(x), "")))

dats[[1]][dats[[1]] == "+"] <- dats[[2]][dats[[1]] == "+"]

apply(dats[[1]], 1, paste, collapse = "")
## [1] "DAAAB" "DDCCC" "ADBAD"
```

I thought this one may be an interesting one to benchmark:

```
Unit: microseconds
     expr     min      lq  median       uq      max neval
 Andrea() 296.693 313.953 321.884 328.4155 2443.051  1000
   Josh() 300.891 314.420 319.551 326.5500 3748.779  1000
  Tyler() 144.148 155.344 159.543 164.2080 2233.593  1000
 Jibler() 174.937 188.932 193.597 198.7290 2269.514  1000
 Alexis() 154.877 167.007 171.672 175.4040 2342.753  1000
 Julius() 394.658 413.317 420.315 429.4120 2549.412  1000
```

[image]

Comment: Why three `lapply`s? you can get `dats` using just one: `lapply(df, function(x) do.call(rbind, strsplit(as.character(x), "")))`.

Comment: @Jiber, I was tinkering and put a tinker answer up.  I'll clean it up.

Answer (score 2):

Based on Tyler Rinker's answer, conceptually it's the same, but using just one `lapply` and `ifelse`.

```
> dats <- lapply(df, function(x) do.call(rbind, strsplit(as.character(x), "")))
> apply(with(dats, ifelse(v1=="+", v2, v1)), 1, paste0, collapse="")
[1] "DAAAB" "DDCCC" "ADBAD"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df<-data.frame(v1 = c("+AA+B", "D++CC", "A+BAD"), 
               v2 = c("DBBAD", "BDCAD","CDCCA"),
               stringsAsFactors = F)


f <- function(x , y){
  xs <- unlist(strsplit(x, split = ""))
  ys <- unlist(strsplit(y, split = ""))
  paste(ifelse(xs == "+", ys , xs), collapse = "")
}

vapply(df$v1, f , df$v2, FUN.VALUE = character(1))
```